# Is it possible in c++ in an 'if' statement to compare 1 string with 2 others like with numbers?

Tags: c++, string, if-statement

```
if (string1 == string2 && string3) {
  cout << "Text: ";
} else {
  cout << "string4";
}
```

I have tried different variations of it, i'm not quite sure if this is the best way to build this type of lines either.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What two comparisons are you trying to perform?  Your code only has one comparison, `string1 == string2`.

Comment: How would you do it with numbers?

Comment: Well i'm trying to say if 'symptom1' equals 'fever' and 'cough' then it give out a possible illness you got.

Comment: But `symptom` **can't be both** "fever" and "cough" simultaneously!

Comment: How could it have two values?!

Comment: `if (string1 == string2 && string1 == string3)` if all three need to be the same or `if (string1 == string2 || string1 == string3)` If the first needs to match one of the other two. I'd be interested to see what the number comparison looks like. If it is similar to the example then it is most likely incorrect as well.

Comment: One symptom (symtom1) can't possibly have two values. What would it be? *fevercough*? Or *fever, cough*? What if they put in *cough, fever*? Or *fever, cough, wheeze*? Or *ache, pain, fever, cough"? What is it that you're actually trying to do here?

Comment: Where does "numbers" come into the questions?

Comment: It was indeed incorrect. Thank you people!

Comment: Tangential: this’ll be a hard way to build a rule-based expert system, and I think they’ve mostly been supplanted by better data and ML techniques.

Comment: The syntax for comparing numbers would be: `if (a == 5 || a == 7)`. Notice how the variable is repeated.

Comment: `string1 == string2 && string3` is not the way to compare `string1` with `string2` and `string3`.   And, if you believe that `int1 == int2 && int3` is the way to compare `int1` with `int2` and `int3` then you are sadly mistaken.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are searching for some kind of facility to make sure that all arguments can be compared with `string1` in your case.

A fold over `&&` (logical AND) may help:

```cpp
template<class T, class... Ss>
bool all_equal(T&& str, Ss&&... ss) {
    return (... && (str == ss));
}
```

In use, it could look like this:

```cpp
int main() {
    std::string string1 = "foo";
    std::string string2 = "foo", string3 = "foo";

    if(all_equal(string1, string2, string3)) {
        std::cout << "Yes\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "No\n";
    }
}
```

The above will print `Yes` because `string1 == string2 && string1 == string3` as the fold expression will test. It'll "unfold" to:

```cpp
return (string1 == string2) && (string1 == string3);
```